# Watching for folder creation in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

is there a way to listen for folder creation in a VSCode extension?

For example, I'd like to trigger the newFolder command as follow:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('explorer.newFolder');
```

and read the created folder to perform other actions inside of that folder.

What I tried?

Well, the executeCommand returns a Thenable<{}|undefined>, I passed a callback into then method:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('explorer.newFolder')
    .then(f=> {
        console.log('folder:', f);
    });
```

But the IDE waits for folder's name, and the then method execution is raised before creating the folder and when logging folder is undefined.

Another option I tried is to register to the workspace change folder event:

```
vscode.workspace.onDidChangeWorkspaceFolders(e => {
    for(const f of e.added) {
       console.log('added folder: ', f);
    }
});
```

But the event is never reached.

Someone with a clue?

Comment: Did you get any answer, I'm interested too :)

Comment: No I have not an answer yet, the project is paused...

Answer (score 0):

I found that `vscode.workspace.onWillCreateFiles` event is triggering when both files and directories are created in vs code explorer. but the issue is that it's not separating files and directories. for example event data is:

```
// when I create a dir
{
 path: "/nodejs-template/dir2/dir21",
 scheme: "file"
}
// when I create a file
{
 external: "file:///nodejs-template/dir2/dir21/file1.js",
 fsPath: "\\nodejs-template\\dir2\\dir21\\file1.js",
 path: "/nodejs-template/dir2/dir21/file1.js",
 scheme: "file"
}
```

as you see when the event data is pointing to a file is has `external` and `fsPath`. I check these two attributes then I check if the `path` does have any  ext at the end (.pdf, .js, .png, ...). it's not accurate but it's the best solution I've found. hope it helps you too